# How to perform multiple actions on the same element using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-plugins

how do I include both drag and resize on a single element.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #header { width: 200px; height: 100px; background: blue; }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").draggable().resizable();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;font-style:times" >

    <div id="header">

      <label> Header <input type="text" value="headerBox" /> </label>
      <input type="button" value="submit" id="headerSubmit" name="submit" />
      <input type="reset" value="reset"/>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try looking into jquery multiple selectors... though i didnt understand ur question, if u provide some code examples it would be helpful...

Comment: I have textbox and 2 buttons that is submit and reset I have put those elements under <div> tag. I am able to drag it but not I am but able to resize.I have add the code above, kindly have a look and please comment

Comment: you need to wrap your code, check out the faq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both draggable and resizable supports chaining mode so you can simplify your code in one line

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#header").draggable().resizable();
 });
```

see demo here.... [DEMO](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery-resize-drag/)
refer this tutorial for more information .....[Draggable and resizable](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example.html)

Comment: nope i am not getting any errors but its just not working. I am able to drag but not resize.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#header").draggable();
$("#header").resizable();

 });
```

see if it works